Albanese in tensor triangular geometry
I am new to algebraic geometry. My question is the following :

We know the notion of Albanese variety and chow group for in algebraic geometry. P. Balmer defined the tensor triangular chow group for any tensor triangulated category which matches with usual chow group of scheme $X$ if we consider the category $D_{perf}(X)$. For schemes Roitman’s theorem tells that the n torsion part of chow group is isomorphic to the n torsion part of Albanese. Now does there is any notion of Albanese in tensor triangular setup?
Does this isomorphism can be realised in tensor triangular geometry ?

Does any notion of Albanese is expected in tensor triangular geometry?
Any references in these context are also welcome.
Thanks in advance.
